# mapping result of JPQLqueryFactory to java map

Tags: java, jpql, querydsl

I am using JPQLqueryFactory:

```
queryFactory.from(qsr,qcr,qsrl)
                    .where(predicate)
                    .select(qsrl.criteriaLabel,qcr.rating.avg())
                    .groupBy(qcr.criteria,qsrl.criteriaLabel)
```

as you can see i am selecting columns have list of string and double so wanted to assign this result to map like

```
Map<String, Double>
```

but i am getting error of type mismatch if i use `fetch()` it will give me list which is not desirable. what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: First of all, grouped fields should be present in select `.select(qsrl.criteriaLabel, qcr.criteria, qcr.rating.avg())` . Because of in select will be 3 values the result will not Map. Please try to change and it will be better if you to attach full error log.

Comment: @borino i actually need two fields only one have lets's say criterialabel  and other it's average that's the reason i am selecting only two. I have translated it from sql query, so I know that is working. All i want to do now is to somehow put it in a map. and i am wondering how to do that?

Comment: perfect, please provide expected SQL.

Comment: You can use a tuple. More [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/reference/html/ch03s02.html)